# Paypal api - Adaptive Payments APP ID

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have 3 different websites that I want to use paypal Adaptive Payments for.

1. Auction
2. Marketplace
3. Funding

Do I need to set-up an new APP with paypal for each one? Or if I got one website approved can I use that APP ID on all my websites?

Also can anyone advise on how to get passed by paypal to get the APP ID, any good tips ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to open a new APP at **apps.paypal.com** and the APP review team will guide you with your requirements as the APP approval depends on your business model and many other factors.

Answer (score 0):

Adaptive payments was discontinued as of 01/12/2017 and PayPal Marketplace is the equivalent to adaptive payments.

You can learn more about the Marketplaces product on the PayPal Developer Portal: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/marketplaces/pp4mp/?mark=marketplaces

You can also register your interest for PayPal Marketplace via the link below -

https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/partner-program/contact-us